# Can anybody tell me what these three white boxes are at the bottom of the power pole?

Tags: power-supply, electricity, distribution-network

Can anybody tell me what these three white boxes are at the bottom of the pole? And how can I tell the number of the circuits on the electrical power pole and what voltages they have? Also, can I see what kind of three phase transformer it is? A delta star?

[image]

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but they could be something related to coaxial distribution?

Comment: @JorenVaes: There is clearly nothing but power distribution on that pole, except for that cable running off to the left. It looks like the white boxes might have something to do with monitoring the status of the large gray box -- which might be a bank of PFC capacitors.

Comment: Those boxes look like they are going to low hanging cable running left of the pole to me.

Answer (score 3):

They look very much like fused disconnectors to protect the cable running to the property/properties served by that cable leaving to the left. Something like these:

[image]

https://www.wt-henley.com/low_voltage_fusegear-pole_mounted_cutouts.html